# Close an opened browser window after 1/2 seconds in Ionic/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

When my Ionic app built within AngularJS completes an order, it posts the order number to a API URL using:

```
var returnUrl = window.open("http://example.com/api/" + ordernumber, "_self");
```

How can I get this window to close after say 2 seconds and then return to my app home page (here is some code I have previously used for a timeout option)

```
.controller('ProductListCtrl', function (Products, $rootScope, $scope, $stateParams, $state, $timeout) {
          $scope.products = Products;

          var timeout;

          $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
              $state.go('app.home');
            }, 2000);
          })
```

Not sure how "self" browser app window can have a controller attached to it?

This window open is part of an existing function below:

```
     function onPay(order) {
     var itemsArr = [];
     var invoice = {};
     var myItems = {};
     var myItem = {};

     myItem['name'] = order.data.name;
     myItem['description'] = order.data.ordernumber;
     myItem['quantity'] = "1.0";
     myItem['unitPrice'] = order.data.amount;
     myItem['taxRate'] = '0.0';
     myItem['taxName'] = 'Tax';
     itemsArr.push(myItem);
     myItems['item'] = itemsArr;

     invoice['itemList'] = myItems;
     invoice['paymentTerms'] = 'DueOnReceipt';
     invoice['currencyCode'] = 'GBP';
     invoice['discountPercent'] = '0';

     var ordernumber = order.data.order; 
     var returnUrl = window.open("http://example.com/api/" + ordernumber, "_blank");
     var retUrl = encodeURIComponent(returnUrl + "/{result}/Type={Type}/InvoiceId={InvoiceId}/Tip={Tip}/Email={Email}/TxId={TxId}");
     var pphereUrl = "paypalhere://takePayment/v2?returnUrl=" + retUrl;
     pphereUrl = pphereUrl + '&invoice=' + escape(JSON.stringify(invoice));
     console.log(pphereUrl);

     return pphereUrl;

     }
```

Comment: Just write close code in opened window )

Comment: @merch89: What's the point of opening the window for less time than the user can see it? Use XMLHttpRequest to make the request instead.

Comment: I mean, that your API url should return html with JS, that close window

Comment: @Quentin Yes, ideally I wouldn't want the browser window to open at all but the data sent to that URL in the background

Comment: @merch89 — So use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Any code hints on turning ```var returnUrl = window.open("http://example.com/api/" + ordernumber, "_blank");``` into a XMLHttpRequest without breaking the function and the URL it builds?